# how to display initial value on redux form date input field

Tags: reactjs, redux, momentjs, redux-form

I am trying to display initial values on my redux form when it first load. Every fields work except the date input field. I tried to use moment to format string (YYYYMMDD) to MM/DD/YYYY and it's not working. No matter how I formatted, the field fail to display and instead showing the default place holder character mm/dd/yyyy until I selected a date. I am using the default redux-form input component date type. How should I do this right? Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting the initial date in your state, you need to provide it as per [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards, so `YYYY-MM-DD`, i.e. 2018-08-22 for 22nd August 2018.

I have never used redux-form library before, but I found a codesandbox example in their [guide](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/), and managed to get it to work [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/32n8221r21) by just relying on them having followed the ISO standard. Feel free to play around with it.